# IP address not changed using Tor via CLI

Tags: linux, networking, tor, ip-address

I have installed Tor via the CLI and rebooted. I call `service tor start` and get prompted to enter my root password. To confirm the service is running I call `service tor status` which confirms Tor is **active**.

However, when I run `curl iconfig.me` or `hostname -I` it returns my public IP which (through IP lookup) is my location.

Can I please get clarification on what is causing my issue and/or whether I need to take further steps to use Tor through CLI correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor client acts as a SOCKS proxy. For traffic to be routed via tor, you need to configure your other software to use the tor SOCKS proxy instead of direct connection.

Comment: I assume then I will need to download torsocks and change my network proxy to `127.0.0.1` and port `9050` into the SOCKS section, followed by a reboot and then change my browsers and apps to **use system proxy settings** ?

Comment: In addition, you might consider adding iptables rules preventing other connections